# how would i stop the build buttons from all changing its state when clicked thanks

Tags: flutter

when clicked the buttons are meant to turn grey. this happens but the problem is that when one button is pressed all the buttons turn grey which i don't want. i only want one at a time.

```
var pressed = false;
  Widget BuildButton(
    String buttonText,
  ) {
    MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly;
    return new Expanded(
        child: new FlatButton(
            shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(
                  15.0,
                ),
                side: BorderSide(color: Colors.black)),
            color: pressed ? Colors.grey : Colors.white, // colour change when clicked
            textColor: Colors.black,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
            child: new Text(buttonText),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                pressed = !pressed;
              });
            }));

          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              new Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [ // buttons start here
                    BuildButton("XXS"),
                    BuildButton("XS"),
                    BuildButton("S"),
                    BuildButton("M"),
                  ]),



                  ]),
```

Comment: Upload the code of your ```BuildButton``` widget @developerC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest moving your `BuildButton` function into its own `StatefulWidget`, this way each time you create a new button, the button is in charge of managing its own state.

I've also moved the `Expanded` widget out of the new `BuildButton` widget to make it more reusable. `Expanded` widgets can only be used inside of `Row` and `Column`. Now your button can be used anywhere!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Home(),
    ),
  );
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: <Widget>[
        new Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            BuildButton("XXS"),
            BuildButton("XS"),
            BuildButton("S"),
            BuildButton("M"),
          ].map((item) => Expanded(child: item)).toList(),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class BuildButton extends StatefulWidget {
  final String buttonText;

  const BuildButton(this.buttonText);

  @override
  _BuildButtonState createState() => _BuildButtonState();
}

class _BuildButtonState extends State<BuildButton> {
  bool pressed = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FlatButton(
      onPressed: () => setState(() => pressed = !pressed),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
        side: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
      ),
      color: pressed ? Colors.grey : Colors.white, // colour change when clicked
      textColor: Colors.black,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
      child: Text(widget.buttonText),
    );
  }
}
```

#### Pro Tip

Use trailing commas to have the dart formatter help you keep your code readable.

Comment: thank you this works but the problem is that everything after the build buttons have now disappeared

Comment: i fixed the error but  i was wondering if  there is  a way to clear the state based on the previous button clicked

Comment: If this helped you please accept it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using pressed variable in all variable, so when you change value of pressed value, all the button change it's color.

You can create a list which contains pressed value for each button.

```
List<bool> pressed = [false, false, false, false];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                BuildButton("XXS", 0),
                BuildButton("XS", 1),
                BuildButton("S", 2),
                BuildButton("M", 3),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget BuildButton(String buttonText, int index) {
    return new Expanded(
      child: new FlatButton(
        shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(
              15.0,
            ),
            side: BorderSide(color: Colors.black)),
        color: pressed[index]
            ? Colors.grey
            : Colors.white, // colour change when clicked
        textColor: Colors.black,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
        child: new Text(buttonText),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            pressed[index] = !pressed[index];
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a Map of different 'pressed' states for each button.

```
Map<String, bool> pressed = {};
Widget BuildButton(
String buttonText,
) {
    return new Expanded(
        child: new FlatButton(
            color: pressed['buttonText] == true ? Colors.grey : Colors.white, // colour change when clicked
            textColor: Colors.black,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
            child: new Text(buttonText),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                pressed['buttonText'] = !(pressed['buttonText'] ?? false);
              });
            },
          ),
      );
}
```